# A question on Fekete's subadditive lemma

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Fekete's subadditive lemma states that for any sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ with $a_{m+n}\leq a_m+a_n$ for each $m,n\geq 1$, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ exists. My question is: if we only know $a_{m+n}\leq a_m+a_n$ for each $m,n\geq t$ (where $t$ is a constant), can we deduce that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ exists?

Answer (score 3):

It is straightforward to modify [this proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fekete%27s_Subadditive_Lemma) to obtain the required conclusion under the weaker hypothesis. Simply, restrict $k,n\geq 1$ to $k,n\geq t$, and instead of $r\in\{0,\dotsc,k-1\}$ take $r\in\{t,\dotsc,t+k-1\}$.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, we can simply modify the standard proof of [Fekete's subadditivity lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fekete%27s_lemma).$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb N}$

*Proof.* We assume that $$a_{m+n} \le a_m+a_n$$ holds for $m,n\ge t$.

Let us denote $L=\inf_{k\ge t}\frac{a_k}k$. We want to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n=L$. It is clear that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n \ge L$.

For any $\ve>0$, choose an $m>t$ such that $\frac{a_m}m\le L+\ve$.

Now any $n\in\N$ can be written as $n=km+r$ with $0\le r<m$. We we rewrite this as
$$n=(k-t)m+(tm+r)=(k-t)m+r',$$
then we have $n$ in the form of a multiple of $m$ with the addition of a number $r'$ such that $r'\ge t$ and, at the same time, $r'<(t+1)m$.

Since we want the multiple $(k-t)m$ to be non-negative, we will assume from now on that $n\ge tm$.

Now we have (for any $n\ge mt$)
$$a_n \le (k-t)a_m + a_{r'}$$
and, consequently,
$$\frac{a_n}n \le \frac{a_m}m + \frac{a_{r'}}n
\le \frac{a_m}m + \sup_{k<(t+1)m} \frac{a_k}n.$$
Since the RHS tends to $\frac{a_m}m$ for $n\to\infty$ we get that
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n \le L+\ve.$$
This is true for arbitrary $\ve>0$, so we get
$$\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}n \le L.$$

Comment: +1 but I beat you by one minute :-)

Comment: At first I was speculating whether I could replace $(a_n)$ by an auxiliary sequence $(b_n)$ which is subadditive and which fulfills $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}n=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}n$. But I did not spot some obvious solution going in this direction - so repeating the usual proof seemed like the most straightforward solution.

Comment: It seems to me that you can more simply rewrite as $n=(k-1)m+(m+r)$, no?

Comment: @ZachTeitler You're right, I was overly generous in the estimate there. In any case, both approaches lead to $n$ rewritten as a sum of two numbers which are $\ge t$.